# Connecting to a SOAP service with 2 way SSL

Tags: php, laravel, ssl, soap, soap-client

Basically, I am trying to connect to a SOAP service with 2 way SSL (HTTP client certificate authentication).

I am using PHP SoapClient for this within Laravel.

This is what I have, and it allows me to connect and returns the expected response. So the method is basically correct and the certificate is fine etc. It's just I am having trouble with what I guess is the 2 way SSL part.

```
$client = new \SoapClient('localwsdlfile.wsdl', array(
    'local_cert' => 'localcert.pem',
    'passphrase' => 'passphrase',
    // 'location' => 'https://wsmurl/login/' // Uncomment to login
));

$response = $client->Get(array(
    "AccessKey" => "accesskey",
    "ProductID" => "SOMEPRODUCT",
    "Scope" => "SOMESCOPE",
    "Parameters" => array('Param' => array('_' => 'DATATOLOOKUP', 'id'=>'MOREDATATOLOOKUP'))
));

print_r($response);
```

The only problem is (obviously because I'm doing something wrong), is I need to add the line `'location' => 'https://wsmurl/login/'` the first time I try to connect, otherwise I get an error "SoapFault Login Required"
I then remove the line `'location' => 'https://wsmurl/login/'`, otherwise, I get an error "SoapFault looks like we got no XML document".
The service provider has a 600 second timeout, where I don't have to "login" again for upto 600 seconds.
After removing this line `'location' => 'https://wsmurl/login/'`, then it works as expected. Obviously, I can't manually add and remove this line, and I guess I am not doing this correctly.

Can someone tell me a better way to do this please?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the location for the login and localwsdlfile.wsdl is different, I could not do it with one call. So we created a function using curl to login and if login is successful it will proceed to the soapclient. Thanks to Brian from freelancer for his assistance here.

```
$client = new SoapClient('wsdl/VocusSchemas/localwsdlfile.wsdl', array(
    'trace' => 1,
    'exception' => true
));

try {

    $response = $client->Get(array(
        // "AccessKey" => "MADAITABNSAATOT1",
        "AccessKey" => "accesskey",
        "ProductID" => "SOMEPRODUCT",
        "Scope" => "SOMESCOPE",
        "Parameters" => array('Param' => array('_' => 'DATATOLOOKUP', 'id' => 'MOREDATATOLOOKUP'))
    ));
```